# How can I compare two revisions in git in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git

I am using the [eclipse plugin for Git](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) on Mac OS 10.6, and I cannot figure out how to compare two version of a file.  I can pull up the file's history, and see all of the commits, with their messages, but I can't figure out how to see what changed in each commit.

This was very easy with subversion, and I'm sure its easy with Git, if you know where to look (but apparently, I don't).

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

To elaborate on my question, is there a way to access `git-diff` in the eclipse plugin?

Comment: The relevant git command is `git-diff`. Is there simply no implementation of that in the Eclipse plugin?

Comment: I guess that is a more succinct way of asking; thank you.  I edited the question to mention 'git-diff'.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was what you meant; it was just the title of your question that threw me off. I did find some things suggesting that you need to enable git as the quickdiff provider in the workspace preferences to allow you to set a revision as a quickdiff baseline and get the advertised quickdiff feature to work. I don't use Eclipse though, so I can't test it.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

From the [EGit User Guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Comparing_Content):

> select a Resource (project, folder, or file) in the project explorer
>   or navigator and right-click an action under Compare With.

I just tested this with EGit 1.3.0. You can compare with a commit, HEAD, previous revision, "branch, tag, or reference", Git index, or any item in History.

Comment: @pkaeding if so, then can you please add that answer here... the links are not working now.

Comment: Yeah, my original answer was lame, link-only answer. Happily, a lot has changed in 3 years. EGit supports a lot of comparing now. I've updated the answer with current info.

Comment: you have no idea how long I've been looking for this. And it turns out to be this simple. Thanks!

Comment: @slothbear does previous revision means the previous commit, I having trouble gettting the difference between revision and the commit. Please forgive me as I am new to git

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya The two terms are based on context — plus you don't often hear "revision" in the git world. The Previous Commit is the last git commit made on the current branch (which might include many files). The Previous Revision is the last commit that changed a single file (or other resource) that you're focused on. My suggestion: start up a test git repository (anywhere on your drive) and start trying things on it. Experiment! The Eclipse Wiki has some descriptions: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Replace_with_Commit