# How can I generate a diff for a single file between two branches in github

Tags: git, github

I need to generate a diff for a single file that will show the differences between two versions, which are actually tags in github. I then want to send this diff to someone via email so a github URL for the diff would be ideal. The github compare view will allow me to do this for all changed files, but that's no good as there are thousands of files in my repo.

I can do this in the command line as follows, but this doesn't help as I need to send the diff to someone via email:

```
git diff tag1 tag2 -- path/to/file
```

I found the command line version discussed here:
[how can I see the differences in a designated file between a local branch and a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611112/how-can-i-see-the-differences-in-a-designated-file-between-a-local-branch-and-a)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

GitHub only exposes the way to show diff between two commits.

Provided those tags actually point to commits, the Url format would be something like

**`https://github.com/{user}/{repository}/compare/{from-tag}...{until-tag}`**

As an example, **https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/compare/v0.9.0...v0.9.5** shows the diff between two versions of the LibGit2Sharp project. This diff includes all the modified files.

If you want to retrieve a URL that targets a specific file:

- Switch to the **Files Changed** tab

[image: changed-tab]

- Click on the **Show Diff Stats** button (This will display the list of modified files as links)

[image: show-diff]

- Copy to the clipboard the link of the specific file you're after... and Tada! You're done.

For instance, given the diff above, the link **https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/compare/v0.9.0...v0.9.5#diff-11** will point to the `LazyFixtures.cs` changes that occured between version v0.9.0 and v0.9.5.

### Update

Following your comment which states that your diff is too big to be rendered through the Web interface, how about reverting to good old command line tooling? You could redirect the output of the diff to a file and then send the file as an email attachment.

```
$ git diff v0.9.0 v0.9.5 -- LibGit2Sharp.Tests/LazyFixture.cs > /tmp/lazyfixture.diff
```

Comment: Hi,it looks like this won't work for me because my diff is too big. I'm getting "This diff is big! We're showing status information only for the first 2,500 files." so I only get the Diff Stats and not the full diffs, even with the #diff links.

Comment: however I think you are right - that's the way to do it. Thanks

Comment: You can also use this Chrome extension https://github.com/danielribeiro/github-diff-highlight-extension to get syntax highlight when comparing branches.

Comment: @plainflavour One more handy tip here in case you run into this again - whenever you have a compare URL like @nulltoken pointed out, you can also just add a .diff to the end of the URL to see the full diff (albeit as plaintext). E.g. `https://github.com/{user}/{repository}/compare/{from-tag}...{until-tag}.diff` [Source](https://github.com/blog/967-github-secrets)

Comment: `https://github.com/{user}/{repository}/compare/{from-tag}...{until-tag}.patch`  give us all patches

Comment: The link to a single file doesn't seem to work, because when loading the compare page fresh, the default tab is Commits rather than Files changed.

Comment: I don't see a **Show Diff Stats** button. Is it gone? Or am I just not seeing it?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but on my private repo, there's no "Files Changed" tab. Instead I have to scroll past the list of commits and there's an "*n* changed files" button there, which I can click and it shows a list of files, where I can copy the link to the particular file.

Comment: Does not work on large commits, try this repository:
https://github.com/nxp-mcuxpresso/mcux-sdk/compare/MCUX_2.12.0...MCUX_2.13.0

Comment: @wjandrea, same for public repo. Per the comment before yours, looks like it has been so for at least almost 3 yrs and no one noticed! Such is how phail Github's web UI is that ppl don't even bother using it.

Answer (score 18):

Here is my workaround when the following issue applies.

> This comparison is big! We’re only showing the most recent 250 commits

Copy the raw view of the file that you want to compare to https://gist.github.com/. Use the two specific commit points that you want to compare. Start with the older commit.

https://gist.github.com/ has a nice side-by-side diff view when you click 'Revisions'.

Comment: Thank you, this was *exactly* the suggestion I needed for https://gist.github.com/ncoghlan/1067805fe673b3735ac854e195747493/revisions! :)

Answer (score 4):

For people who want to only see (not download) the history/revision of code changes of a file in the GitHub web page:

Go to that file on GitHub, then select **History**. This will open a page with a list of commit links like below.

[image: Screenshot of a GitHub file history page showing that commit titles and hashes are clickable]

On clicking on it, it will show the code changes. After clicking the history, you can click on packages to see package level all files commits.

In Eclipse, you can compare the history using **EGit** plugin and "Right click ->Compare with" on the file.
[How can I compare two revisions in git in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396649/how-can-i-compare-two-revisions-in-git-in-eclipse)

Comment: For a commit of 5000 files, this doesn't take me to the single-file diff. From [this history](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/commits/master/docs/extensibility/menucommands-vs-olemenucommands.md), try finding the delta to that file from [this huge commit](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/commit/8d6efbe8e9ba5fe4f3917116b92b87b1facfba78#diff-e4605636854882b5745e2aafa7271e06).

Comment: @Kanagavelu, but It will show code change against the **prior version only**. No way to diff before that.

Answer (score 1):

Since this still isn't possible here's a browser-based diff-tool method. It does not leverage automation but only requires the ability to install Chrome extensions:

1. Install Diff Tools for Chrome browsers: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/diff-tools-text-pdf-doc-o/lkcdojpmjehlniamnglpjlldkoonlomb
2. Open Diff Tools ( http://iblogbox.com/devtools/diff/ )
3. From GitHub go to the BEFORE commit, tag, or branch, open the file, then click on the <kbd>Raw</kbd> button to get the raw file view, select-all and copy, then put in the left-hand side text box in Diff Tools
4. Repeat step 3 but for the AFTER file and paste into the right-hand-side box in Diff Tools
5. Click <kbd>Compare Now</kbd> and perform your diff ad-hoc

Comment: +1 because the website (2) is effective in Mozilla Firefox **without** (1) installing the extension for Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I used [nulltoken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14503451/1601953) to put together a simple convenience script for pulling up a diff between two commits on GitHub from the command line.

You can find the [full script on gist](https://gist.github.com/fritz-c/d5b755aeacbd6cf68b7a6463f8dbe1c5), but here are the good bits:

```sh
# Parse the following patterns for repo urls to get the github repo url
# https://github.com/owner/repo-name.git
# git@github.com:owner/repo-name.git
BASE_URL="https://github.com/""$(git config --get remote.origin.url | sed 's/.*github\.com[/:]\(.*\).git/\1/')""/compare"

if [[ "$#" -eq 1 ]]; then
  if [[ "$1" =~ .*\.\..* ]]; then
    # Handle "git hubdiff fromcommit..tocommit"
    open "${BASE_URL}/$(git rev-parse "${1/\.\.*/}")...$(git rev-parse ${1/*\.\./})"
  else
    # Handle "git hubdiff fromcommit"
    open "${BASE_URL}/$(git rev-parse "$1")...$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
  fi
elif [[ "$#" -eq 2 ]]; then
  # Handle "git hubdiff fromcommit tocommit"
  open "${BASE_URL}/$(git rev-parse "$1")...$(git rev-parse "$2")"
fi
```

It accepts as arguments branches, commits, and anything else that can be resolved by `git rev-parse`. I used `open`, which only works on macOS for opening webpages, so if you're on a different environment you'll want to tweak that.

As with nulltoken's answer, in order to point to a single file in the diff, you'll have to click on the file's title to make the anchor string appear in the url bar, which you can then copy.

Comment: any way to get the anchor string for a comparison that doesn't show the desired file because there's too many of them?

Comment: @sgarg The anchor is "diff-<md5 of the filename>" - not documented AFAIK - but it annoyed me and I guessed it.

Comment: The anchor now appears to be using SHA256 instead of MD5: `diff-<sha256 of filename>`. In particular, this means that the MD5 anchor **_no longer works_**.