# Single-file diff between two commits

Tags: github

In github, is it possible to show the diff of a single file between two commits?

One can readily diff two commits, and it is possible to link to the anchor for a specific file in those two commits, but all files are included in that view.  For example, https://github.com/adamginsburg/APEX_CMZ_H2CO/compare/a94a962db51e0f4e73ec3ba4170a0ca8269548da...adamginsburg:master#diff-22

I would like a similar view, but without the other files.

(I know how to do this on the command line with git, but I want to share this link with collaborators, so the command line approach is not relevant for this question)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I generate a diff for a single file between two branches in github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500240/how-can-i-generate-a-diff-for-a-single-file-between-two-branches-in-github)

Comment: 1 year later I'm trying to do the same... guess still can't be done using github... sad thing

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate. comparing files across branches is different than selecting endpoints in history in a single branch for one file.

Answer (score 4):

I think your question can be consider a duplicate of this one :

[How can I generate a diff for a single file between two branches in github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500240/how-can-i-generate-a-diff-for-a-single-file-between-two-branches-in-github)

Unfortunately, the accepted answer doens't answer your expected behavior.

I really tried to exclude the other files without success, and since there not seems to have other means to filter it out but html anchor pointer, I guess what you already have is what best available with Github to pin point the change you want to talk about with your peers.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend you to use [Vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [Git History](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.githistory), I know is not the same as having in Github but it allows you to see the changes of the code according to an specific file or the entire project, comparing with the actual code, see all the changes of specific file through the commits, I work with this tool and this is helpful for me, hopefully it will be helpful for you.

[Git History Example Usage](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DonJayamanne/gitHistoryVSCode/master/images/gitLogv2.gif)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GitHub File Diff extension available for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-file-diff/lmhbkinmjbfihpkihjdhcagnigpklinh) and [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/github-file-diff/).

Disclaimer: I made this extension.